# Applying a perspective transform to an image

Tags: javascript, imagemagick, fabricjs, image-manipulation, php-gd

I have to increase the width of any given image from top to bottom with some aspect ratio. 
Are there any solutions in PHP GD / imagemagick / fabric js or is there any other application?

[First image is the Source. And I need the output like the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLcqr.png)

Comment: There is jmagick but I do not think it supports -distort. You can use AJAX to pass co ordinates from JavaScript to Imagemagick/php and I suppose it depends on what functionality you want. It looks like you can use graphics magick with node.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ImageMagick**'s `+distort` operator like this:

First, create the starting shape:

```
convert -size 100x300 xc:green shape.gif
```

[image]

Now distort it to widen the base:

```
convert shape.gif  -virtual-pixel none \
   +distort Perspective '0,0,0,0  99,0,99,0  0,299,-60,299  99,299,160,299' result.gif
```

[image]

There are 4 pairs of numbers. The first pair says pixel [0,0] (top-left corner) in the input image must appear at [0,0] in the output image. The second says pixel [99,0] (top-right) must appear at the same place in the output image. The third says that the bottom-left pixel, must be at [-60,299] in the output image - i.e. 60 pixels to the left of its current position and outside the current image boundary. Likewise the bottom right pixel must appear 60 pixels to the right of its current position and therefore outside the existing image base.

The virtual-pixel setting of `none` makes newly created pixels transparent. There are other possible settings for the virtual pixel, which can be listed as follows:

```
identify -list virtual-pixel
```

**Output**

```
Background
Black
CheckerTile
Dither
Edge
Gray
HorizontalTile
HorizontalTileEdge
Mirror
None
Random
Tile
Transparent
VerticalTile
VerticalTileEdge
White
```

If you want to make your code a bit more independent of the dimensions of the image, you can parameterize them using `fx` operators and the new `magick` command in place of `convert`:

```
magick shape.gif  -virtual-pixel none \
   +distort Perspective '0,0,0,0  %[fx:w-1],0,%[fx:w-1],0  0,%[fx:h-1],-60,%[fx:h-1]  %[fx:w-1],%[fx:h-1],%[fx:w+60],%[fx:h-1]' result.gif
```

Comment: "the new magick command in place of convert" in imagemagick version 7. I see you managed to get inline fx working Mark

Comment: @Bonzo Yes, thank you! See - you **can** teach an old dog new tricks ;-)